# AngularJS HTTP interceptor: request function freezes the app

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

the scenario is simple:

before any ajax call is being made I need to check if `refresh_token` has expired. If it has, I send a new request to refresh it. After the operation completes, I allow the original request to being executed.

But the problem is, if I want to send my extra ajax request, I get my app frozen. Why ? Am I now allowed to use any additional services here?

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($timeout, $q, $injector, $rootScope) {
    var AUTHService;

    $timeout(function () {
      AUTHService = $injector.get('AUTHService');
    });

    return {
        request: function(config) {
            if (AUTHService) {
                if (AUTHService.checkTokenExpired()) {
                    $q.all([AUTHService.RefreshToken()]);
                    return config;
                } else {
                    return config;
                }
            } else {
                return config;
            }
        }
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: You can use JWT libary .. https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt

Comment: I believe `AUTHService.RefreshToken()` is causing a circular reference calling the interceptor again.